# Install php pear on mac os

Tags: php, macos, pear

How to correct instal pear for php. I store all for web server in /opt/local.
But pear want be installed to /Users/. How change this folder.

```
 c8-bc-c8-d8-eb-65:tmp macbookpro$ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar 

    Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
    change individual locations, type the number in front of the
    directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
    accept these locations.

     1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /Users/macbookpro/pear
     2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
     3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
     4. Binaries directory                            : /Users/macbookpro/pear/bin
     5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /Users/macbookpro/pear/share/pear
     6. Documentation directory                       : /Users/macbookpro/pear/docs
     7. Data directory                                : /Users/macbookpro/pear/data
     8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /Users/macbookpro/pear/cfg
     9. Public Web Files directory                    : /Users/macbookpro/pear/www
    10. Tests directory                               : /Users/macbookpro/pear/tests
    11. Name of configuration file                    : /Users/macbookpro/.pearrc
```

Comment: You can change the dirs by pressing the corresponding number on that line.

Comment: thak i choose 1 and set /opt/local all installed fine.

Comment: Alright if that solved your question I placed as an answer below so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the dirs by pressing the corresponding number on that line.